# Cursor with default parameters

Tags: oracle11g, cursor

**EMP_SAL_INFO**
This cursor has 2 default parameters C_SAL and C_DESIG based on both default and user defined params it should fetch records. If should display the records as with default values first and then with user specified values and then both.

DECLARE

```
DESIG EMPLOYEE.DESIGNATION%TYPE :='&DESIGNATION';
SAL EMPLOYEE.SALARY%TYPE :=&SALARY;

    CURSOR EMP_SAL_INFO(C_SAL EMPLOYEE.SALARY%TYPE DEFAULT 75000 , C_DESIG EMPLOYEE.DESIGNATION%TYPE DEFAULT 'Asst. Professor') IS
            SELECT ENO,FNAME||' '||LNAME AS ENAME,DESIGNATION,SALARY FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE DESIGNATION=C_DESIG AND SALARY>C_SAL OR DESIGNATION=DESIG AND SALARY>SAL;
            RECORDS EMP_SAL_INFO%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN
    OPEN EMP_SAL_INFO;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('With Default Values....');
    LOOP
            FETCH EMP_SAL_INFO INTO RECORDS;
    EXIT WHEN EMP_SAL_INFO%NOTFOUND;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(RECORDS.ENO||' '||RECORDS.ENAME||' ' ||RECORDS.DESIGNATION||' '||RECORDS.SALARY);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE EMP_SAL_INFO;
    END;
```

Comment: And the question is ...?

Comment: I have explained what exactly I want as an output..But I am not getting it by using above

Comment: We don't have your tables nor data and can't test code you wrote. Saying that "you aren't getting it" is pretty much useless. Please, post test case (by editing the question) - CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO sample data which would be the *input*, as well as desired *output*.